# Symfony / Laravel - shared Auth

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, authentication

im searching for the best practice for the following problem:

I have got an existing laravel system and created a new symfony2 system. Now I would like to combine these two systems by using the same auth.

I handled this problem once by auto-registering a laravel-user in the registration process of Symfony, using FosUserBundle in Symfony and the included Auth of Laravel. But this isn't the happiest solution, not only because the User has to login twice.

Anyone got an idea for a good practice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illuminate components (which make up Laravel) are individually small components that can be used without the entire framework. If I were you, I would try including the authentication components specifically and mimic how Laravel handles auth to keep session / auth cookies symmetrical.

https://github.com/illuminate/auth

Comment: Thank you. I managed it to use LDAP both in Symfony and Laravel. For me this was the best way.